# Replacement For <font>

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2015

We have finally upgraded from `Visual Studio 2005` to `Visual Studio 2015` and I see that with `HTML5` the `<font>` tag is no longer supported.  In `Visual Studio 2005` I would use this as my syntax:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <font>This is where you would enter text</font>
</asp:Content>
```

However, since the `<font>` tag is no longer supported what is the appropriate replacement?  Is it `<span>` or `<h1>` etc?  All I am using it to indicate is text is going to be entered between these two tags, I use `CSS` for any other formatting needs, just need to know the appropriate updated tag for my `HTML` to display this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<font>` is pretty pointless without size, face, color, etc. attributes. So in your example just remove the tags.
If you want to actually style the text use CSS styles.

```
.someclass {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
}
<span class="someclass">This is where you would enter text</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<span>` is what you want - an inline, no-presentation tag that will be treated the same as your no-presentation `<font>`. An `<h1>` or similar would be block layout, and come with some default styles.